# what could be the secure alternative way of writing response.url in the redirect method in JS?

Tags: xss

Security team reported following code as a Cross-site scripting.

```js
 redirect: function redirect(ajax, response, status) {
  window.location = response.url;
 });
```

They gave the sample of writing in better way

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myDiv").on("click", "button", function(){
 var eid = $("#eid").val();
 $("resultsDiv").append(eid);

 });
 });
```

But How I do it for my code?

Comment: The  so called "sample" makes no sense! And I don't see how the redirect function is cross site scripting.

Answer (score 0):

It is potential cross-site scripting on the response.url parameter, because if that contains user input and the user enters `javascript: alert(1)`, it will be run in some browsers. Whether this is exploitable depends on the circumstances (how and with what parameters is `redirect` called and what browser is used).

The other code really doesn't make any sense though. :)

As for the fix, it also depends on the above. Make sure callers don't include user input, and/or in `redirect()` you can implement input validation (eg. response.url starts with 'http', does not contain 'javascript:', etc.)

Also note that if not cross-site scripting, it can stil be an open redirect.